# Is possible to know how many AVPackets for one AVFrame ?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is possible to know how many AVPackets for one AVFrame ?

I would like to implement a function that user can play video in reverse way.

I don't want to put temp datas in local file in some reasons so I would like to implement it via AVPacket directly.

I found that in Audio, every pts of AVPacket is equal to dts of AVPacket.

and I can reverse the AVPacket, put AVPacket to decode from last one to first one,

and then I got the AVFrame.

but in Video is difference, have no idea how to implement it.

Is possible to calculate exactly AVPacket for one AVFrame ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know AVPacket, but encoded MPEG frames have internal order and grouping.
Simply speaking, MPEG compression consist of intra-picture encoding and inter-picture encoding. This means that some frames have references to the previous frames.

This frame grouping is called GOP (group of pictures).
Within the GOP, frame order can't be changed.

For reverse way video playback, the original video must be encoded accordingly (e.g. I frame only encoding).

Comment: is possible calculate GOP to know how many packets for exactly frame ?

Comment: I don't understand what's the packet. GOP is one of encoding options. https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Video-Options Could be variable in some mode. Usually it's not stored in the encoded movie file.

Comment: Just for the sake of idea, you could fully decode all the pictures of a single GOP and then render each picture in reverse order.

Comment: I can't really find the regular of GOP in FFmpeg, got packets from av_read_frame, I can see info of decode timestamp & play timestamp for each packet, but regular was changed sometimes